# Datatables Error where column is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to see what is going wrong here:

```
var TableName = $('#List').DataTable({
        autoWidth: false,
        pagingType: "full_numbers",
        order: [[ 1, "desc" ]],
        serverSide: true,
        processing: false,
        ajax: "datatables.cfc?method=getTable",
        columns: arr,
        columnDefs: arrDefs
    });
```

Here is how `arr` and `arrDefs` are coming:

```
var arr=[];
var arrDefs = [];
datacolumns.split(",").forEach((element)=>{
arr.push({data:element.trim()})
arrDefs.push({className: "editable alignCenter"})
});

arrDefs.push({
    width: "1em", className: "deleteCol", orderable: false
});
```

But I am getting an error:

> TypeError: column is undefined jquery.dataTables.js:1722:5
>       jQuery 7

my JSON

```
[
  {
    "DT_RowData": {
      "pkey": 1
    },
    "DT_RowId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "delete": "<img class=\"deleteButton\" src=\"delete.png\" alt=\"delete1\" />",
    "title": "Dewey defeats Truman"
  },
  {
    "DT_RowData": {
      "pkey": 2
    },
    "DT_RowId": 2,
    "id": 2,
    "delete": "<img class=\"deleteButton\" src=\"delete.png\" alt=\"delete2\" />",
    "title": "Men walk on Moon"
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to add in some more info? What does a sample of the JSON from `datatables.cfc?method=getTable` look like? How is `datacolumns` populated?

Comment: Thank you. And how is datacolumns populated prior to `datacolumns.split(",")`? What does that data look like?

Comment: it is coming as comma seperated value like `authorid,firstname,lastname,email`

Comment: and the deleted is the manual td column which i am adding at the end of the for each loop

Comment: OK - thank you again. Because you are using `serverSide: true`, DataTables expects a very specific structure for your JSON (server to client) - and will send very specific requests (client to server). Your JSON does not fit with this requirement. See DataTables [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60801535/how-can-i-load-a-set-number-of-rows-from-a-table-on-pageload-and-only-load-furth/60804184#60804184).

Comment: but it is working, if i hardcode pass the values, but when i try to use the the above, it gives me that error